# Android Sdk issue with Ubuntu 20.04lts

Tags: android, ionic-framework, environment-variables

Ubuntu only finds ANDROID_HOME when not running with sudo. When sudo is used, it does not find the installation. Please help!

---

administrator@administrator-System:~/ap_ids/app$ **cordova requirements**

Requirements check results for android:

Java JDK: installed 1.8.0

Android SDK: installed true

Android target: installed android-29,android-28

Gradle: installed /home/administrator/gradle-6.4.1/bin/gradle

---

administrator@administrator-System:~/ap_ids/app$ **sudo cordova requirements**

Requirements check results for android:

Java JDK: installed 1.8.0

Android SDK: not installed

Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.

Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

Android target: not installed

android: Command failed with exit code ENOENT

Gradle: not installed

Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Could not find Android SDK directory.
Might need to install Android SDK or set up 'ANDROID_HOME' env variable.

Some of requirements check failed

Answer (score 0):

Global paths should be set at `/etc/profile`. So put your `export ANDROID_PATH ...` statement there.

> But why would you want to run `cordova` in `sudo`?

[Quoting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104727/add-a-path-in-path-globally-for-every-user):

> Many Linux distributions support the Linux Standard Base `/etc/profile.d` directory where configurations such as additional paths directives can go without touching the stock system files.

```sh
cat >> /etc/profile.d/some_name.sh << \EOF
  PATH=$PATH:/path_to_android/bin
EOF
```